# Spring Boot MongoDB connection via Ssh Tunnel

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, database-connection, ssh-tunnel

I have my spring boot source code on other server and my MongoDB is on another server. Both servers can be accessed via Ssh tunnel which is created by a `key.pem` file. Now I want to connect my code with MongoDB. So I would like to know what configurations do I need to provide in the application.properties file to achieve same.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use SSH tunnel and forwarding port.